# How does AWS Amplify cloudformation parameter.json work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I recently started using AWS Amplify and I've had experience using vanilla cloudformation. Most of it makes sense except for the `parameters.json` part.

It seems that Amplify generates cloudformation templates for the resources we use, but it also generates a `parameters.json` file, which I thought was the equivalent of the `Parameters` section of cloudformation, but it doesn't seem to be.

In Amplify `parameters.json` the content is just on `object` with key-value pairs. Whereas in cloudformation, parameters has a defined syntax as noted [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

Also in `parameters.json` it seems to be able to make a `Ref` call in the same manner as cloudformation templates. Does anyone know what is parsing the `parameters.json` file and replacing `Ref` with actual value?

For example in the `storage` category, the `parameters.json` file has key like this

```
"authRoleName": {
    "Ref": "AuthRoleName"
},
```

`AuthRoleName` seems to be defined in both `amplify-meta.json` under the `backend` directory, but it's also defined in `team-provider-info.json` under the `amplify` directory.

Does anyone know which `AuthRoleName` file it's using? From what I read in the docs, both `amplify-meta.json` and `team-provider-info.json` is auto generated.

A lot of these questions came up because I was curious if I could execute the autogenerated CF templates in CF manually in cloudformation UI. When I tried and copied the Parameters section in and the Metadata section in, I got invalid syntax.

This led me to think amplify is using it's own parser to generate a finalized CF template and executing it in CF. I tried searching through the cli repo, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Oh man, good question.  Sorry this is an opinionated non-answer, but I'd love to see this answered.  How to use and modify the CFN resources that Amplify creates is a huge gap in this product in my opinion, as if no-one considered that a developer might change their mind or make a mistake.

Comment: @Khon Did you find the answer? I also interested in this topic.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late but might still be useful. You have a couple of questions here:

> Does anyone know which AuthRoleName file it's using? From what I read in the docs, both amplify-meta.json and team-provider-info.json is auto generated.

Yes, both are auto generated. The main difference being team-provider-info.json contains the parameters for all your amplify environments (assuming you have more that one and this file is shared between the team members) while amplify-meta.json contains only the info related to the currently checked out environment. In short, the values in amplify-meta.json are the ones currently used.

> How does AWS Amplify cloudformation parameter.json work?

The way amplify works is by creating a cloudformation template for each function/api gateway/storage element (This is a partial list of Amplify Categories), each mini template will have its own parameters.json file (the one you mentioned). Then amplify will combine all of these files in a single template under amplify/backend/awscloudformation/nested-cloudformation-stack.yml (which is a json file!). This file will have references to each template as they get uploaded into your deployment S3 bucket (can be found in amplify-meta.json) and the contents of the parameters.json files included inline.

- More info about these *nested* templates can be found [AWS Cloudformation User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html)
- More info about Amplify CLI inner workings can be found [Amplify Usage](https://haverchuck.github.io/docs/cli/init?sdk=js) and [Amplify Architecture](https://haverchuck.github.io/docs/cli/concept?sdk=js)