# AWS S3 Bucket is public but makes itself private after I upload a file

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I configured a folder in my s3 bucket to be public but when I upload a new file it makes **the whole folder** private again so I can't access any of the photos I uploaded with the react native app that I'm making.

I discovered there is a property named level that can be set to public when I'm uploading, but even after doing that I'm still having the same problem:

```
try {
          const response = await fetch(image);
          const blob = await response.blob();
          const res = await Storage.put(fileName, blob, {
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            level: 'public'
             
          });
          console.log(res);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Error uploading file:', err);
        }
```

After uploading a file into that folder if I try to access any of the photos I uploaded I get this:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>VVA4P84N464GN15S</RequestId>
<HostId>GoHg1p7ZnMCgY2B0CL8CsJARtEU3DCmesh+K1BQiOGX8++prVp/GoqddtcSbZBLi4iTQ38KDbVk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is how I made it public:
Went to the bucket, selected the folder, clicked on actions and then clicked on make public with ACL.

[image]
Please help. Hopefully somebody knows what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should explain how you made the S3 objects public.

Comment: I followed this instructions: https://aws.amazon.com/en/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/ basically I went to my bucket, selected the folder, clicked on actions, clicked on make public with ACL. Added a screenshot. Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the photo URL? Are you asking Amplify for a URL to the object, or are you just manually creating one such as `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/someid/public/dog.png`? I suspect Amplify's notion of "public" is not the same as yours, or S3's.

Comment: I'm getting it in 2 ways. First by going to the s3 console and copying the URL of the object. And I'm getting the same url from the response I get when I upload the file from my app.

Answer (score 1):

Amplify's `level='public'` feature is not what you think it is. It doesn't make an S3 object public (in the sense that S3 considers an object to be public).

What it does is allow all users of your Amplify app (including  unauthenticated users) to request a pre-signed URL for the object, and then use that pre-signed URL to fetch the object. See this Amplify [bug report](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/659) and this [feature request](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/518).

My understanding is that to make an uploaded S3 object public so that you can access it using an unsigned object URL such as `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/someid/public/dog.png`, you have to:

1. add `{acl:"public-read"}` when putting the object
2. ensure your parameters.json file includes the `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission (and potentially in s3-cloudformation-template.json too)

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I need. But what parameters.json do you refer to? I don't have anything called PutObjectAcl on my files so I guess that's why it's not working. Do you mean my app.json? I have: amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json, awsconfiguration.json, amplifyconfiguration.json, amplify-build-config.json and amplify-gradle-config.json. And in my amplify/backend/storage I have cli-inputs.json

Comment: Or maybe you mean that I should put that into: console, bucket permissions, where it says Bucket Policy (which is expecting a json) .

Comment: I believe that Amplify creates parameters.json (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658197/how-does-aws-amplify-cloudformation-parameter-json-work)]. `s3:PutObjectAcl` is an action that your code needs in its IAM policy. It already has `s3:PutObject` but it needs to be able to set the ACL also. It's not a bucket policy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just uploading a file and set it's level to public might not be enough depending on your configuration.

There also are `ACLs` and `Bucket policies` that you should check out.

e.g.

> S3 Block Public Access provides four settings. You can apply these settings in any combination to individual access points, buckets, or entire AWS accounts.

which means if your settings are set to `IgnorePublicAcls` for example, the public level of your file would be ignored.

[aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html)

Comment: Probably that's not the problem because when I set public with ACL everything works fine. The problem is when I upload another file into the folder, it makes the folder (not the uploaded file) private again.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is go to s3 bucket and look for Permissions tab, Bucket policy, click edit and put:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that the access is public.