# How Do I Know What Key Value Pairs Are Allowed In The parameters.json For AWS Amplify?

Tags: json, aws-amplify

I currently have the `parameters.json` file for my AWS Amplify where I would like to learn all the available key/value pairs.

```
{
  "AppSyncApiName": "name",
  "DynamoDBBillingMode": "PROVISIONED",
  "AuthCognitoUserPoolId": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": [
      "userPoolID",
      "Outputs.UserPoolId"
    ]
  },
  "AuthModeLastUpdated": "timestamp"
}
```

Does AWS Amplify provide documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Does AWS Amplify provide documentation for this?

Answer: **No** (or at least I couldn't find any). It seems the specific properties you are looking for are on the CloudFormation docs for the specific tools you are using (eg. DynamoDB, Cognito)

---

Best I could find is this post:
[How does AWS Amplify cloudformation parameter.json work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658197/how-does-aws-amplify-cloudformation-parameter-json-work)

The answer on that post talks about using [AWS Amplify categories](https://here:%20https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js/#scoped-configuration---storage).

The answer on that post links to here, which is shows some cloud formation parameters, but not any of the ones you have:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

It seems that since the JSON is based on cloud formation templates, you have to dig down into the AWS CloudFormation docs for the tools you are using and find the parameters there.

Here's the DynamoDB CloudFormation docs for example and the closest thing to `DynamoDBBillingMode` is `BillingMode`:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
  "Properties" : {
      ...
      "BillingMode" : String,
```